# Microservices architecture boundaries

Tags: microservices

I would like to implement gambling website with the following possibilities:

- as a player I would like to get list of games
- As a player I would like to like games
- As a player I would like to see recommended games(based on likes or time spent 
  on a particular game by users)
- As a player I would like to start/end a particular game

For above requirements, I will need at least 3 micro services from my opinion:

- GameCatalog Service - it will contains games and categories of games
- GameRecommendation Service - it will analyze which game is commended for any users or particular user based on likes and time spent on a game
- UserManagement Service - it will contains user accounts

Microservices will be communicate to each other by Apache Kafka. Each microservice will have own database.

What else microservice I should have to like or start/end games in this scope?

Should 'like' functionality be in GameRecommendation Service as well?

Where is better to keep data concerning likes and 'timeSpent' in GameRecommendation service database or another one?

Comment: 'at least 3 micro services'. No, all this can be in one service. Why do you think you have to separate?

Comment: Since I think each service solves different tasks. GameCatalog responding for game create|update|delete|listing. GameRecommendation is planned to use with machine learning that is to say it will do some analyze of data. UserManagement Service responding for user create|update|delete|listing.

Comment: Single service for all this staff sounds like monolith application.

Comment: A monolith can be the right way to go, especially when you consider the https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MicroservicePremium.html

Comment: I think you're definitely over engineering. What you've described amounts to a few simple functions and data structures.

Comment: Monoliths are not evil. Inadecuate solutions based on wrong premises are. That said, I encourage you to start the project as a monolith. The different boundaries of your business will appear eventually. MS are meant to be an architectural style addressed to solve software life cycle managment and development issues that are common in large applications. Probably, you are not even close to having these issues. We don't know why you have decided to go that way, but your questions and doubts make us things that such architecture, right now, is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:  I am relatively new to both Microservices and DDD.*

Are you familiar with **Domain Driven Design**?
It has a concept called [Bounded Contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) which may help you.

In DDD, Bounded Contexts are a way of managing the complexity involved in modelling large Domains.  They serve to group closely related concepts and operations.

I think you should read up on them as Bounded Contexts tend to map very well to Microservice Boundaries.

I'd write more about this, but I'm at work :P

Answer (score 0):

What are the actions in your scenario and who are the subjects?

1) `users` want to `log into` your application. This one is easy to separate out. The job is clearly defined. This would do for a service.

2) `users` have *interaction* with `games`.

There are several topics:

a) The actual state of `games`

b) Storage and analytics of current / past `games`

c) `users` want to like `games`.

> Microservices will be communicate to each other by Apache Kafka.

Why that?

> What else microservice I should have to like or start/end games in this scope?

Perhaps you rethink your "microservice". From my perspective, there is no microservice needed to *like* or to *begin* / *end* games. These are actions (=`events`), a user does in your system. Since *starting* and *ending* games has an impact on the `states` of current games, i.e. one game is added to the list of current running games and its state is persisted as *running*.

> Should 'like' functionality be in GameRecommendation Service as well?

A `user` *likes* `a certain game` is an *event* and as such is published as a message. This message could be consumed by many subscribers: i.e. the recommendation service as well as an analytics service.

> Where is better to keep data concerning likes and 'timeSpent' in GameRecommendation service database or another one?

There are several places where this information could go into, e.g. analytics - for monitoring platform users as a whole, how much interaction every user has with every game and so on. Depends on your usecase.

This is one possible design. But besides there are many other possible ones.